# CakePHP: Redirecting to a random View

Tags: cakephp

I have a CakePHP website that acts as a questionnaire. It moves the user from one question to another as they click "Next". Now, for each person, I want the system to randomly select the questions they will receive.

Each question is built as a view that redirects to another view. Does anyone have a good idea on how to build it so that the when the user clicks "Next" they are redirected to a random view?

Thanks a lot everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was creating a "paths" table in the database with each record representing a possible path through the questionnaire. Then I had the controller grab a random record, divide it into an array in a Session variable, then use those array values in the "redirect" part at the end of every function. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you don't have a unique identifier in the database for each form.  In that case, you need some way to identify them.  I'm going to use a simple array of view filenames here, but you'd probably be better off creating a questions table which has the view name as a field, and linking submitted answers to the question.

```
// always make sure that the current view gets passed as a parameter
echo $form->create('Question', array('url'=>array('action'=>'next', $currentView));
...
echo $form->submit('Next');
```

in your controller:

```
var $questionViews = array('q1', 'q2', 'q3'); // filenames of the views

function next($view = null) {

    if(isset($this->data)) {
        // save answers to database, session, etc
        if(/*save successful*/) {
            // redirect to the same action, which will load a new view because
            // no form data was passed
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'next'));
            exit();
        }
    } 

    $toRender = null;  // view to be rendered
    if($view && in_array($view, $this->questionViews)) {
        // render the explicitly passed view
        $toRender = $view;
    } else {
        // grab a random view
        $toRender = $this->questionViews[array_rand($this->questionViews)];
    }

    $this->set('currentView', $toRender); // used by form action
    $this->render($toRender); // explicit call to render stops the default view from being rendered
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... why are you building it with a different view for every question? It would seem much easier to have each question stored in the database, use a generic template view with variables like $question and $answers[] as template variables and then use just that 1 view to display each question.